# Workflow has SPContext.Current when run manually but not when run "On Change"?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, workflow

If I run this workflow manually it works fine.  When I let it run automatically "on edit" SPContext.Current is null.  How do I get access to SPContext.Current when it is run automatically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SharePoint routinely runs your workflows under completely different processes. At least, you can expect your workflow activities to appear under:

- an IIS worker process,
- the `owstimer.exe` process,
- any arbitrary executable that interfaces with SharePoint (e.g. a console application).

In respect to the event that triggered the workflow **and** the *complexity* of the workflow scenario (!!) SharePoint selects the process that will actually execute it. Thus a long running workflow when triggered from ASP.NET (i.e. the IIS worker process) is automatically rescheduled to run under `owstimer.exe`.

The result is you cannot use `SPContext.Current`. In workflow activities you have to use a `WorkflowContext` instance which provides a `Web` property. Your activites shall declare a dependency property of type `WorkflowContext` to get access to it — read more in [MSDN here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.workflowactions.workflowcontext.aspx). The VS item template will provide you with the necessary code.

Example:

```
public partial class LogEventActivity: Activity
{
    public static DependencyProperty __ContextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("__Context", typeof(WorkflowContext), typeof(LogEventActivity));

    [Browsable(true)]
    [ValidationOption(ValidationOption.Required)]
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)]
    public WorkflowContext __Context
    {
        get
        {
            return (WorkflowContext)base.GetValue(__ContextProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            base.SetValue(__ContextProperty, value);
        }
    }
}
```